# how to create shadow inside of an element

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to find a way to have a shadow on the inside of an image but I can only manage an outer shadow. .showSlide is a div element btw

```
.showSlide {
display: block;
width:100%;
height:350px;
}

.showSlide img {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
border-radius: 15%;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #000 inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #000 inset;
box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #000 inset;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aysanc0h/) for a solution

Comment: cheers, this works!

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
.showSlide::before {
content: "";
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
-webkit-border-radius: 15%;
-moz-border-radius: 15%;
border-radius: 15%;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 12px rgba(0,0,0,.6);
}
```

and edit:

```
.showSlide {
display: block;
width:100%;
height:350px;
position: relative;
}

.showSlide img {
width: 100%;
height:100%;
border-radius: 15%;
}
```